# The repository primary signature validity period has expired. (NU3037)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

*Hello everyone,
I am new here, so I am sorry for all of my mistakes that I won't do willingly.*

In my Asp.Net Core **5.0** project on Macbook, I used PostSharp from NuGet packages. I was using **3.1**, but I changed all projects to **5.0** to fix the problem. I haven't found the Mac version of PostSharp from its website. So I downloaded the '.exe' file, but it was run by Xamarin. Therefore, I am so confused now. When I run the solution I got 300 errors and many of them contain the 'NU3037' expression. I tried many times to delete PostSharp from NuGet packages and then, again downloaded it. But it doesn't work. Here is one of the error messages:

> /var/tmp/postsharp/cache/DependencyRestore/5.0.400/net5.0-sdk5.0.400-osx-x64--ps6.9.8.0-bcb8619.deps.proj: Error NU3037: Package 'runtime.fedora.24-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired. (NU3037) (DevFramework.Northwind.Business.Tests)

Thanks for help.

Comment: So you are using VS for Mac? From the error message, it seems it’s more related to this NuGet package => PostSharp itself. Not sure what `.exe` file you downloaded, try to ask this question here: [GitHub – NuGet](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues) , and here: [Contact owners](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PostSharp/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will do what you suggested after trying to fix it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Everything has been solved about PostSharp. I **included .exe file** of **PostSharp(6.9.9)** to solution items and another error has occurred about serializing. I asked the PostSharp support team, the last exception was totally about to change the [Serializable] attribute to **[PSerializble]** attribute. I am glad to share this with you.

Answer (score -2):

I had error with runtime.win.System.Console 4.3.1 before. I deleted that row in my csproj file and that worked for me